# c# No error but unresponsive program?

Tags: c#, runtime-error

My project to to create a c# windows,that simulates a fake GPS,that sometimes doesnt receive data,and most of the time receives data.

I have simulated that using Random class of c#.

It stores all this in sql server table m in db ex_1.

the program starts once i click GPS ON!,gps starts,and collects fake data,simulates periods of no data,meanwhile,I should be able to query the database,using other text boxes and buttons:

1. One text box take the time and the object(I shud track several objects,for now i track just A)
   and give me the location at the time.
2. Another text box take the location and object name,and give the time at which it was at that     location.

The retreival of information from DB works fine on its own, the problem is the button GPSON! once it works nothing else does!

Now I am aware that I have an infinite loop in the program,so I was wondering,is it not possible to have other button working simulatenously,and this works infinitely UNTIL I press close,which ends the program?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class GPS
        {
            public String ObjName;
            private Int32 Loc;
            private DateTime date;

            public void setLoc(Int32 Location)
            {
                Loc=Loc+Location;
            }

            public Int32 getLoc()
            {
                return Loc;
            }

            public void setDate(DateTime s)
            {
                date = s;
            }

            public DateTime getDate()
            {
                return date;
            }

            public GPS(String n)
            {
                ObjName =String.Copy(n);
                Random rnd1 = new Random();
                Loc = rnd1.Next(50);
            }
        }

        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RAMAPRIYASR17A6;Initial Catalog=ex_1; Integrated Security=TRUE");
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd=new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cs.Open();
            SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select TIME from m where NAME=@name and LOCATION=@location",cs);
            SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", tb2.Text);
            SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@location", tb3.Text);
            SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader reader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                answerlabel.Text = reader.GetString(0);
            }

            cs.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cs.Open();
            SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select LOCATION from m where NAME=@name and TIME=@time", cs);
            SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", tb2.Text);
            SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@time", tb1.Text);
            SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader reader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                answerlabel.Text = reader.GetString(0);
            }

            cs.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GPS a = new GPS("A"); 

            Random rnd = new Random();
            Random time_skip = new Random();

            while(true)
            {  
                Int32 skip_or_not = time_skip.Next(-61, 600);//if <0 then GPS off

                //We check if skip_or_not < 0

                if(skip_or_not<0)//GPS off or off radar
                {
                    Int32 tChangePos = rnd.Next(-50, 50);
                    a.setLoc(tChangePos);

                    DateTime w = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan timew = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20, 0,0);//20 mins off radar
                    DateTime combined = w.Add(timew);
                    a.setDate(combined);
                }
                else
                {
                    Int32 ChangePos = rnd.Next(-6, 6);
                    a.setLoc(ChangePos);

                    a.setDate(DateTime.Now);
                }

                string stmt = "INSERT INTO m(TIME,LOCATION,NAME) VALUES(@time, @location,@name)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, cs);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

                cmd.Parameters["@time"].Value = a.getDate().ToString("t");
                cmd.Parameters["@location"].Value = a.getLoc().ToString();
                cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = a.ObjName.ToString();

                cs.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cs.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the shot of the program:

[image: Screen shot of Prog]

I am a beginner in c#, so Im not sure what I am doing wrong. I do think it has something to do with that infinite loop,not sure how to do it another way.

Thank you :)

Comment: `while (true)` loops often take a very long time to complete ;) Use a timer instead.

Comment: Do you understand what `while(true)` mean?

Comment: Yes this is possible. You should have a look at [threading](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26148/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-of-n).

Comment: WHile(true) runs the loop infinitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking the main thread with your infinite loop. You should use another thread for that part of your software. Also, if you ever want to stop that functionality (a GPSOFF button for example) you should change while(true) to while(some_var) and before starting the thread set some_var to true and when you want to stop the thread do some_var = false. This will end the loop gracefully.

```
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class GPS
        {
            public String ObjName;
            private Int32 Loc;
            private DateTime date;

            public void setLoc(Int32 Location)
            {
                Loc=Loc+Location;
            }

            public Int32 getLoc()
            {
                return Loc;
            }

            public void setDate(DateTime s)
            {
                date = s;
            }

            public DateTime getDate()
            {
                return date;
            }

            public GPS(String n)
            {
                ObjName =String.Copy(n);
                Random rnd1 = new Random();
                Loc = rnd1.Next(50);
            }
        }

        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RAMAPRIYASR17A6;Initial Catalog=ex_1; Integrated Security=TRUE");
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd=new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        private Thread myThread;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myThread = new Thread(trackGPS);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cs.Open();
            SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select TIME from m where NAME=@name and LOCATION=@location",cs);
            SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", tb2.Text);
            SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@location", tb3.Text);
            SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader reader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                answerlabel.Text = reader.GetString(0);
            }

            cs.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cs.Open();
            SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select LOCATION from m where NAME=@name and TIME=@time", cs);
            SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", tb2.Text);
            SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@time", tb1.Text);
            SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader reader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                answerlabel.Text = reader.GetString(0);
            }

            cs.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myThread.Start();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void trackGPS() 
        {
            GPS a = new GPS("A"); 

            Random rnd = new Random();
            Random time_skip = new Random();

            while(true)
            {  
                Int32 skip_or_not = time_skip.Next(-61, 600);//if <0 then GPS off

                //We check if skip_or_not < 0

                if(skip_or_not<0)//GPS off or off radar
                {
                    Int32 tChangePos = rnd.Next(-50, 50);
                    a.setLoc(tChangePos);

                    DateTime w = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan timew = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20, 0,0);//20 mins off radar
                    DateTime combined = w.Add(timew);
                    a.setDate(combined);
                }
                else
                {
                    Int32 ChangePos = rnd.Next(-6, 6);
                    a.setLoc(ChangePos);

                    a.setDate(DateTime.Now);
                }

                string stmt = "INSERT INTO m(TIME,LOCATION,NAME) VALUES(@time, @location,@name)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, cs);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

                cmd.Parameters["@time"].Value = a.getDate().ToString("t");
                cmd.Parameters["@location"].Value = a.getLoc().ToString();
                cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = a.ObjName.ToString();

                cs.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cs.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IM going to try this and get back :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the infinite loop is in the GUI thread, thus making the GUI unresponsive. Read up on `BackgroundWorker`s. You neeed to move your processing to a background thread, and `BackgroundWorker` is an easy way to do that.

Comment: So if I move this to the background,it would still be an infinite loop right? Also would it be possible to run two button methods at once,like I click button 1 it runs,button 2 is clicked and also runs simultaneously since button 1 procedure is not over?

Comment: It is possible to have several operations running simultaneously, triggered by individual buttons. The buttons should start background operations, then return from the click method immediately. The background operations will continue running.